# Looping ant design tag color in React Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, antd

I use Ant Design and data which coming from API. I assume the data like this

```
data = [
  {
     name: "John",
     job: "Freelancer",
  },
  {
     name: 'Bob',
     job: 'UI Designer'
  },
  {
     name: 'Sam',
     job: 'CEO'
  },
  {
     name: 'Alex',
     job: 'Mobile Dev'
  },
  {
     name: 'Jess',
     job: 'Web Dev'
  },
];
```

I want to return the job with Tag from Ant Design which the tag has a different color

```
<Tag color="green">green</Tag>
<Tag color="cyan">cyan</Tag>
```

I have looped the data. but I don't know how to make the data have a different color tag

```
data.map((el) => {
//This example doesn't have color
  return <Tag>{el.job}</Tag>
})
```

How to achieve that ? And sorry i'm not good enough in English. I hope you understand what i mean
Or you can visit code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-wind-cs4bjr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, add a property something like **tagColor** for each object.

```
data = [
    {
     name: "John",
     job: "Freelancer",
     tagColor: "red"
    },
    {
     name: 'Bob',
     job: 'UI Designer'
     tagColor: "green"
    },
    {
     name: 'Sam',
     job: 'CEO'
     tagColor: "blue"
    },
];
```

Then in the loop, use that property to dynamically add colors. Like,

```
data.map((el) => {
  return <Tag color={el.tagColor}>{el.job}</Tag>
});
```

**Updated**

If the colors can be random, you can place all your colors in an array. And you can pick colors one by one using index or even a randomiser. Something like,

```
const colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
data.map((el, i) => {
  return <Tag color={colors[(i%colors.length)]}>{el.job}</Tag>
});
```

It will pick colors in the array one by one based on index.

Comment: [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-wind-cs4bjr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Actually, those colors that I added are just random ones. I didn't look on antd for the colors. You can take a look at antd and fill that array with those colors.

Comment: It's actually not specific to antd. It's a general implementation. So I didn't care about those specific colors. You can grab the color list from antd and replace that array with their colors

Comment: And also, I just updated the code. Replaced 'i/colors.length' with 'I%colors.length'. Check that out. It will fix other issues

Comment: Can you explain me about this code `{colors[(i%colors.length)]}` ? How it works ?

Comment: Sure. The '%' means modulus. There is a concept called modulus in mathematics. Not going into much detail on it. The mod will give you a number within a specific range.
For eg,
0%3=0
1%3 = 1
2%3=2
3%3=0
4%3=1
5%3=2
...
The pattern continues, what happens here is we are performing mod operation with the number 3, so the result will always be within 0,1,2 (3 values starting from 0). So in your case we need to pick a color from the array using an index. And we need to ensure that the index stays within the array.

Comment: If we use mod with the array length, we will always get an index which resides in the array, not more not less, just in.

Comment: Ahh i see. Thanks for your time